# Refactoring two methods using indexOf

Tags: javascript

These two methods are almost identical, how could they be refactored into one method?

```
method1 = (value) => {
    var example =  array.filter(row => row.key.indexOf(value) > -1);
    this.setState({state: example});
}

method2 = (value) => {
    var example =  array.filter(row => row.otherKey.indexOf(value) > -1);
    this.setState({otherState: example});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take what varies between the two functions and separate it from the function by making those items arguments that must be passed into the function:

```
var method = (value, key, state) => {
    var example =  array.filter(row => row[key].indexOf(value) > -1);
    this.setState({state: example});
}
```